# Linked Server to Oracle DB produce wrong result

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with querying Linked Oracle DB Server from SQL Server. I am querying the view on Oracle box and that view contains a function within the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE    someColumn  =  someFunction(anotherColumn)
```

The query returns correct number of rows when ran from Oracle client. When is executed from the SQL server it returns far to many results. By examining the query I have found the the function in the WHERE clause is not getting applied. This is all I can say as I have no access to the Oracle BOX. I am using OLE DB Oracle provider.

What could casue that problem ?

Comment: Are you using OPENQUERY syntax in your linked server definition? I think that is the option whereby the query is passed as-is to the linked database (in which case the function should work as it is being executed by/in oracle). The other option (I forget the syntax) attempts to parse the SQL, in which the function may be ignored.

Comment: @davek I am not using `OPENQUERY`, My query looks like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LinkedServer..Scheme.View`, But I've tried to issue the same query from `OPENQUERY` with the same result like this SELECT* FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM View)

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is to take a trace of what actually arrives in Oracle (using TKPROFfor example), to see if the function has in some way been stripped out on the way.

Comment: @davek Thanks for the comments. Please see my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was due to **Oracle Provider for OLE DB**. When I have changed the provider to **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle** it works fine. It took me a while to figure it out as the problem is uncommon and Google won't give any hint.